# main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Tags: magento2, product, module, blocks, review

I'm using Magento 2.4.3 and I'm loading a custom module using someone else's code from the link

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-Product-Reviews-only-by-customer-who-purchased-the/m-p/109338/highlight/false#M6143

Override the Review form block with your custom block.

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Form" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Review\Form" />
</config>
```

Add condition for the customer in your custom block

app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Review/Form.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Review;
class Form extends \Magento\Review\Block\Form
{
/**
 * Customer Session Factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory
 */
protected $_customerSession;
/**
 * Order Collection Factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
/**
 * Registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_registry;
/**
 * Review data
 *
 * @var \Magento\Review\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_reviewData = null;

/**
 * Catalog product model
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $productRepository;

/**
 * Rating model
 *
 * @var \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory
 */
protected $_ratingFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface
 */
protected $urlEncoder;

/**
 * Message manager interface
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface
 */
protected $messageManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
 */
protected $httpContext;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Url
 */
protected $customerUrl;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $jsLayout;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json
 */
private $serializer;

/**
 * Form constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder
 * @param \Magento\Review\Helper\Data $reviewData
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
 * @param Url $customerUrl
 * @param array $data
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json|null $serializer
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
    \Magento\Review\Helper\Data $reviewData,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Review\Model\RatingFactory $ratingFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $reviewData, $productRepository, $ratingFactory, $messageManager, $httpContext, $customerUrl, $data);
    $this->jsLayout = isset($data['jsLayout']) ? $data['jsLayout'] : [];
    $this->serializer = $serializer ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json::class);
}

protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    if ($this->isCurrentCustomerPurchasedThisProduct()) {
        $this->setTemplate('Magento_Review::form.phtml');
    } else {
                    $this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::no_review_form.phtml');
                    // You can set null here if you don't want to load any template
                    // $this->setTemplate(null);
    }
}

public function getCurrentCustomerId()
{
    return $this->_customerSession->create()->getCustomer()->getId();
}

public function getCustomerOrders()
{
    $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect(
        '*'
    )->addFieldToFilter(
        'customer_id',
        $this->getCurrentCustomerId()
    );

    return $orders;
}

public function getCurrentProduct()
{
    return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
}

public function isCurrentCustomerPurchasedThisProduct()
{
    $product_ids = [];

    foreach ($this->getCustomerOrders() as $order) {
        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
            $product_ids[$item->getProductId()] = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }

    if (in_array($this->getCurrentProduct()->getId(), $product_ids)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

My custom message in:

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/no_review_form.phtml

```
You can not add the review on this product as you have not purchased this product yet.
```

I added this as a module and had to include a module.xml file in /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc and registration.php in /app/code/Vendor/Module which is pretty standard.

I get an error displayed at the top of the product page on the front end.

```
"An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details."
```

Nothing is in the exception.log but the below is in the system.log

```
main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Review/Form.php:163
```

Line "163" in Form.php from above is:

```
if (in_array($this->getCurrentProduct()->getId(), $product_ids)) {
```

Full Stack trace from system.log is below

```
#0 /bitnami/magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Review/Form.php(122):Vendor/Module\Block\Review\Form->isCurrentCustomerPurchasedThisProduct()
#1 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(225): Vendor/Module\Block\Review\Form->_construct()
#2 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(155): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->__construct()
#3 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Form.php(111): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->__construct()
#4 /bitnami/magento/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Review/Form.php(112): Magento\Review\Block\Form->__construct()
#5 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Vendor/Module\Block\Review\Form->__construct()
#6 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#7 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create()
#8 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php(46): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()
#9 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(272): Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock()
#10 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(252): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance()
#11 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(229): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock()
#12 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(134): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock()
#13 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process()
#14 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(365): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process()
#15 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#16 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent()
#17 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 /bitnami/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(68): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#19 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#20 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#21 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#22 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(224): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#23 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(237): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#24 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild()
#25 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(114): Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates()
#26 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Controller/Block.php(86): Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout()
#27 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Controller/Block/Esi.php(19): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block->_getBlocks()
#28 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi->execute()
#29 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->___callParent()
#30 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#31 /bitnami/magento/generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Controller/Block/Esi/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#32 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->execute()
#33 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#34 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->___callParent()
#35 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#36 bitnami/magento/generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Controller/Block/Esi/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#37 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\PageCache\Controller\Block\Esi\Interceptor->dispatch()
#38 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#39 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#40 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#41 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#42 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#43 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#44 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#45 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch()
#46 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#47 /bitnami/magento/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#48 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#49 /bitnami/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#50 /bitnami/magento/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#51 {main} [] []
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to find the solution ?

Comment: I ended up using "Advanced Review" from MAGETOP.COM.